# Google Analytics: View Filter by Request URI - does this work?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I think this should be pretty straight forward but if I have a url(s) with a request URIs such as:

*/en/my-hometown/92-winston*
*/en/my-hometown/92-winston/backyard*

and I want to set up a GA view which only includes this page and any subpages, then does the following Filter work in Analytics?

[image: Request URI Filter Example]

Will that basically filter against and URI which specifically contains *92-winston* or do I need to wrap it in a fancy regex? I'm not that great with RegEx.

Thanks! Apologies in advance if this is ridiculously easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this regex, if you know exactly that the URI will start with "/en/my-hometown/92-winston":

```
^\/en\/my\-hometown\/92\-winston.*
```

This captures URI strings that start exactly with "/en/my-hometown/92-winston" and also include anything that may come after that, for example

- /en/my-hometown/92-winston
- /en/my-hometown/92-winston/backyard
- /en/my-hometown/92-winston/some_other_page

Just beware that if you have more than one "Include" filter in GA, then you need to make sure you aren't actually excluding more data, as multiple include filters are "and"ed. Always test your new filters in your test view as well.

Comment: thanks for this! Is the ^ carat required for the regex? Does the one in my example not work at all? or would *\*92\-winston* work?

Comment: Your regex is just looking for exactly "92-winston" and nothing else, so you just need to take into consideration any other strings before that. The carat indicates the start of the string. It's not needed if you know that there could be text that comes even before "/en/" in the page path (URI), for example "another/path/en/my-hometown/92-winston". So if you know there won't be any string before the "/en", then you can leave the carat in. Also, you could try ".*92\-winston", but in this case you basically ignore any string before that. So something like "/blah/blah/92-winston" would pass.